# CSS3 inline flexbox with ul list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, flexbox

I'm trying to set up a left meny where the `li` elements stretch to the entire height of the screen whatever the size of the screen.

I can't have the li elements filling the whole height of the screen with the css3 flex property. I've been looking at a good documentation here:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I'm working with a `ul` list of elements. Don't know if this is causing the problem ..

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
#left-drawer-menu {
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#left-drawer-menu li{
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 20%;
}



<ul id="left-drawer-menu">
    <li data-icon="contacts"><span class="km-icon km-mostrecent"></span>Available 1</li>
    <li data-icon="globe"><span class="km-icon km-mostviewed"></span>Available 2</li>
    <li data-icon="camera"><span class="km-icon km-organize"></span>Available 3</li>
    <li data-icon="organize"><span class="km-icon km-featured"></span>Available 4</li>
    <li data-icon="settings"><a href="#profile"><span class="km-icon km-action"></span>Available 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The problem is what exactly?

Comment: I can't have the li elements filling the whole height of the screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to :

a) set height 100% to all the elements chain, including the ul, the body and the html

b) set at least flex-grow to the elements

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
}

#left-drawer-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 90%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#left-drawer-menu li{
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/LbxzB/)

Comment: Thanks Vals, I can see it working on fiddle but I can't have it working on my website, I've been trying to reproduce what you said with no luck, will keep trying